# Как правильно сформировать SQL запрос?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Доброго времени!

Использую CI. Как правильно организовать отображение строк, которые предназначены только для одного пользователя?

**Текущий запрос:**

```
function get_detail_transactions($id = NULL)
{
    if ($id)
    {
        $sql = "
            SELECT *
            FROM {$this->_db}
            WHERE id = " . $this->db->escape($id) . " AND sender = 'johndoe' OR receiver = 'johndoe'
        ";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        if ($query->num_rows())
        {
            return $query->row_array();
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

где sender и receiver - логин пользователя.

**Файл контролера:**

```
function detail_transaction($id = NULL)
    {
                $user = $this->users_model->get_user($this->user['id']);

        // make sure we have a numeric id
        if (is_null($id) OR ! is_numeric($id))
        {
            redirect($this->_redirect_url);
        }

        // get the data
        $transactions = $this->transactions_model->get_detail_transactions($id, $user['username']);

        // if empty results, return to list
        if ( ! $transactions)
        {
            redirect($this->_redirect_url);
        }

        // setup page header data
        $this->set_title( lang('users history detail') );

        $data = $this->includes;

        // set content data
        $content_data = array(
                        'user'              => $user,
            'cancel_url'        => $this->_redirect_url,
            'transactions'      => $transactions,
            'transactions_id'   => $id
        );

        // load views
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('account/detail_transaction', $content_data, TRUE);
        $this->load->view($this->template, $data);
    }
```

Comment: А показать, что получается в переменной $sql - не?

Comment: Я выполняю запрос SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE (id = '29' AND sender = 'johndoe') OR (receiver = 'johndoe').

Comment: Синтаксически к запросу претензий нет. Жаль только, этот текст запроса не может быть получен показанным кодом...